# Where is Gralhund Villa located within Waterdeep?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms, waterdeep-dragon-heist

In *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist*, a significant portion of one of the chapters takes place in "Gralhund Villa".

There are locations given for several of the noble Houses in the first chapter, but I can't find anything giving even an approximate location for Gralhund Villa. I've marked this question as 5e, but will accept information from any edition.

**Where is Gralhund Villa located within Waterdeep?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### A neighborhood in the North Ward.

From *Waterdeep: Dragonheist*:

> Gralhund Villa sits in the middle of an upper-class residential neighborhood in the North Ward.

More specifically, we have a street name:

> Nim’s errant nimblewright is in Gralhund Villa on Saerdoun Street, in the North Ward.

Consulting the DM's map included with the module, we can pinpoint the exact location:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! I especially appreciate the extra effort with the maps.

Answer (score 3):

You can find Gralhund Villa (and other places in Waterdeep and Toril as well) on [this interactive map](https://map.fantasymaps.org/toril/1492.7223/16.364724673218042/43.62551097576306/-76.75384335473773) based on *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist*, made by myself digitizing official source material.

[image: Map of northeast Waterdeep, showing Gralhund Villa]

Comment: This is a fantastic tool, one I have used very successfully in a campaign. That said, link-only answers are problematic here, because what if the link dies? A screenshot of the map zoomed/panned to an appropriate location to show Gralhund Villa’s location in Waterdeep would solve that. Moreover, since this is fan-work, the answer should at least be clear about that, and if possible try to back it up—if the creators of that map cite their sources, that would be great and worth quoting, otherwise perhaps trying to square their results on this particular point against official sources.

Comment: You are very right. This is a map I made based on artwork related to Dragon Heist and using a platform for Digital Humanities (openhistorymap), also developed by myself. The sources are at the moment the dragon heist map and a huge map of Toril that I personally transformed into the vectors you can see when zooming out.

Comment: Oh wow, didn’t realize you’d made this. I’m pretty sure this is the one we used, though if you made it very-recently perhaps not. But it is very nice; thanks for the answer pointing it out, and thanks for the great tool!

Comment: When using resources that you have created/own to answer a question (or indeed ask one) you should add a disclaimer to that effect.